# .Net Core ApiController redirection - loosing authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

What to do to be automatically authorized in target controller when performing redirection?
Currently I get "Unauthorized" and I don't know why as I was already authorized in controller A.

Currently I have this in controller A:

```
[HttpGet("archive/{cycle}")]
public IActionResult GetArchiveCreated(string cycle) {

string url = $"../../archivecontroller/{cycle}"; //controller B - route archivecontroller/cycle_name
return Redirect(new Uri(url,UriKind.Relative).ToString());
}
```

EDIT 2020-10-19: Important note might be that I'm using JWT token passed in HTTP header for authorization.

Comment: There are many ways to implement authorization and many ways how users can authorize. Please describe how users authorize and show why you know the user is authorized in controller A and how you know the user is not authorized in controller B.

Comment: I can execute any other method in Controller A - hence authorization works (I do use authorization attribute on controller level) `[Route("api/controllerA")]
    [ApiController]
    [EnableCors("Cors")]
    [Authorize(Roles = Role.X)]` . When I debug method with redirection it simply gives me Unauthorized on the redirected Controller B. If I would be not authorized in controller A I would not even execute redirection method.

Comment: Ok, you're using attributes and you require a role. Is it the same role on your controller b? Note: It's telling you "not authorized" - so your user might have permissions to execute action a but not action b  - depending on what you specified in your Authorize attribute...

Comment: In both controllers there are same rules of providing access - same Role X can access both. I can trigger both controllers methods from same user separately - issue exists only when I do redirection from one to another.